# Error in sudo apt-get update (N: Ignoring file 'google.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension)

Tags: apt, google-chrome, sudo

when I run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get this :

```
Reading package lists... Done
N: Ignoring file 'google.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'gcl' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
```

I tried to fix it by

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gcl
```

but I received this :

```
mv: cannot stat '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list': No such file or directory
```

how to fix this ?

Comment: First, ask yourself how you made those non-existent sources. They likely did not make themselves. Looks like you somehow managed to mangle a Google Chrome source. Once you identify what source it really should be, fix the file. Or delete the file.

Comment: @user535733

after I wrote

cd /etc/apt

then

grep -rw karmic *

this appeared

"grep: sources.list.d/google.list.save.1: Permission denied
grep: sources.list.d/google.list.save: Permission denied"

so I think the problem is in this two sources

Comment: That command did not make the bad sources. It merely found them already made.

Comment: how to find the bad sources? I've searched but didn't find a way

Comment: You know the bad sources. You told them to us: `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list.save.1` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gcl`. Read those files to see if they are something you want to keep, or if you recall how/why you made them. If not, delete them.

Comment: I deleted them, and there aren't any problems now.
I'm really grateful for your help

Comment: @MohamedAhmed04 by just deleting the files, you won't get Chrome updates.

Comment: @heynnema has a valid point - one hopes you didn't delete without looking first.

Comment: @MohamedAhmed04 Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark icon just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix it this way...

`cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` # change directory

`sudo mv gcl google-chrome.list` # rename it back to original

`sudo rm -i google.list.save.1` # delete this bad .save file

`ls -al *chrome*.list` # confirm you only have one such .list file

**Update #1:**

- The contents of the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` file that you deleted was:

`sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` # recreate this file

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

---

- And the file at `/etc/cron.daily/google-chrome`, should have the following line modified:

`sudo -H gedit /etc/cron.daily/google-chrome` # edit this file

Change this:

```
REPOCONFIG="deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main"
```

To this:

```
REPOCONFIG="deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main"
```

Comment: when I write:

"deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main"

this message appears on terminal: 
"** (gedit:3176): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-position not supported"

Comment: @MohamedAhmed04 It's probably just noise. Edit the file again with `sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` and see if the contents are as intended.

Comment: @MohamedAhmed04 You're very welcome.